# Does "酒入ってる" mean drink alcohol?

Tags: translation

I read this line from this blog: https://boundary.futureartist.net/diary/104512

> これはほんまにお酒入ってるのかと疑うほど、甘くて美味しくてなんともならんかった。

Does "酒入ってる" mean drink alcohol? Why not just use 飲む?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「お酒{さけ}が入{はい}っている」or in the shortened form as in the example「お酒{さけ}入{はい}ってる」means "to contain alcohol". The sentence as a whole would translate like

> 「これはほんまにお酒入ってるのかと疑うほど、甘くて美味しくてなんともならんかった」
>
> "This is ***so*** sweet and delicious, it (almost) makes you doubt whether it even contains alcohol."

or something to that effect. The "so (x) that it makes you doubt whether it contains alcohol"/「ほんまにお酒入ってるかと疑うほど」here is used in the rhetorical sense to emphasize how different the taste is compared to that of other alcoholic beverages.